# Why does the program print wrong value of shared object's global variable?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I built a shared object from following `C` code with the following command :

```
gcc -fPIC -shared libx.c -o libx.so
```

libx.c

```
extern int printf(const char *, ...);

int libvar = 250;

void libfunc(){

    printf("%d,",libvar);    
}
```

Then i linked the following `C` code against the `libx.so` library with the following command:

```
gcc -no-pie -lx -L ./ -o main main.c
```

> -no-pie : To tell the compiler to generate an ELF executable instead of a shared object (Because that's what my compiler does by default).

main.c

```
extern void libfunc();

int main(){
    libfunc();
}
```

Now, when launching the program, theoretically, the dynamic loader will map the shared library `libx.so` somewhere onto the address space of the running process (./main) and will resolve the symbols `libfunc` & `libvar` (Changing stuff in the `.got` and `.plt` segments for `PIC`), it will eventually resolve `printf` symbol and then print the value of `libvar` which is `250`.

But the program prints some weird value:

```
root@afr0ck:~# ./main; printf "\n"
-1076465840
```

I've been debugging for longtime to understand what's going on but i can't figure it out !

Comment: Is this even the same code - your output doesn't even have the comma? What GCC version, which platform - your linking doesn't work for me on Linux (wrong order of dependencies)!

Comment: It's really weird the comma thing ! I didn't even notice that. I'm working on a folder which has only the above 2 sources. I recompiled with the same commands as the above & everything work but still the same problem.
I'm using `Debian` 32-bit and `GCC` version 6.3.0. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Interesting, I get a linker error if I don't put the `-lx -L ./` at the end; even then I needed to install the lib in `/lib`, it wasn't found in cwd. Ubuntu, 64-bit; 6.3.0 here too.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, this is so embarrassing, I was using a wrong shared object in `/lib`. I forgot to copy the new library.

Comment: @afr0ck: you should delete your question. Next time, please check your computer before asking.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I really spent 1 hour debugging. The 2 libraries were very similar & the only difference was in the `printf`'s string format, that's the reason why i couldn't find it out.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Should i delete the question ?

Comment: This just means that you need to improve your debugging know-how

Comment: Yes, you should delete your question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Question could not be deleted. However, it may help anyone out there !

Comment: No, because you don't explain anywhere what is wrong. It is *not* the code that you have shown in your question (but a a matter of system misconfiguration).

Comment: @afr0ck well, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from now on

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because i couldn't delete it, i have flagged the question and asked a moderator to delete it as the post doesn't describe a programming problem & it doesn't have specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

I changed a bit your example. My `libfunc`  contains now:

```
void libfunc(){
  printf("in libfunc libvar=%d\n",libvar);    
}
```

Notice that order of arguments to `gcc`  matters a *lot* (and your arguments to `gcc`  are in the wrong order). Read more about [*Invoking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

I compiled your library with

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wall libx.c -o libx.so
```

Then I compiled your `main.c`  with

```
gcc -Wall main.c -L. -lx -o main
```

Then execution failed with

```
 ./main: error while loading shared libraries: libx.so: cannot open 
                      shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And this is normal, see [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)

To correct that error, either explicitly set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  to contain the directory having `libx.so` (e.g. `.`) e.g. by typing in the *same* terminal running your program something like 
 `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`

or set appropriately the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) by compiling your program with

```
  gcc -Wall main.c -Wl,-rpath,. -L. -lx -o main
```

In both cases I get

```
  in libfunc libvar=250
```

as expected when running `./main`

BTW, using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) would have helped you to find your bug (not in the code you show but a system misconfiguration). And you could also have compiled both the library and the executable with `-g`  and then used the `gdb`  debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a dinâmica variable libvar is allocated unsafely in the heap and can be changed by other programs in the OS that use the same memory.

Best practice would be use a constant or pass the value every time it's called if you need to change it.

Comment: This is not how ELF targets work (which appears to be what the OP is using).

Answer (score -1):

Someone pointed out to the library being in `/lib`, so i went to check it out & i found out that i was using the wrong library that defined the same symbols `libfunc` & `libvar` and in function `libfunc` there was some other `printf` that caused the program to print the wrong value.
So, technically, the difference between the two libraries was in the format string argument in `printf` which i didn't check out while debugging.